# Detectar palabras duplicadas con Regex

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intentando encontrar todos los elementos duplicados que hay en una frase.

Para ello, estoy probando con el siguiente código, pero únicamente detecto la primera palabra duplicada y me gustaria reemplazar todas, independientemente de que tengan mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Este es mi código:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

String regex = "\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE /* Insert the correct Pattern flag here.*/);
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = in.nextLine();
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
        input = input.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
    }

    // Prints the modified sentence.
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Por ejemplo, en la frase:

```
Hola hola hOla
```

Debería de imprimir sólo:

```
Hola
```

Actualmente me imprime:

```
Hola hOla
```

Comment: ¿Por duplicados te estás refiriendo a duplicados consecutivos? ¿Puede haber signos de puntuación entre duplicados o sólo espacios?

Comment: `o` y `0` no son iguales, por ello el regex falla.

Comment: Fundamentalmente busco duplicados consecutivos.

Comment: Respecto al comentario de Luiggi, o y O son diferentes, pero se supera gracias al Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
String regex = "\\b(\\w+)\\b(\\s+\\1)+\\b";
```

Explicación:

> Las `\b` nos indican el límite de la palabra, sin ellas por ejemplo un
>   `"Hola OLA"` coincidiría con `Hola` ya que quitando la H el patron
>   sería correcto `"ola OLA"`, pero queremos que mire las palabras
>   **completas**.
>
> La `\w` nos indica caracter (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) y el `+` que puede tener varios caracteres de
>   longitud. Por tanto `\w+` nos indica que es una palabra.
>
> El `\s+` nos indica que puede contener uno o mas espacios.
>
> El `\1` guarda nuestro primer bloque de la expresión (lo que contenga
>   `\w+`), por tanto ha de ser igual.
>
> El `+` final significa que puede repetirse varias veces la expresión
>   `\s+\1`.
>
> Por tanto al final obtenemos una expresión formada por
>   Palabra1+(Espacio+Palabra), pudiendo repetirse (Espacio+Palabra1) n veces.

Comment: Puedes explicarnos qué hace la expresión regular que nos muestras? Puede ser de ayuda para los demás.

Comment: Listo, espero que lo aclare un poco. No tenía mucho tiempo antes y le di una respuesta rápida. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la solucion. Tengo otra duda respecto de tu regex, se supone que los word boundaries \\b (patron buscado) \\b tienen que ir en parejas de apertura y cierre o estoy equivocado?

Comment: Si, creo recordar que era mejor así lo que yo te lo edite rápido la primera vez que estaba con curro.

Comment: @pitiklan no es necesario que vayan de a pares. Coinciden en una posición entre un `\w` y un `\W` o el principio/final del texto. De hecho, el `\b` utilizado en el medio es innecesario, ya que siempre existirá un límite de palabra completa entre una palabra y un espacio

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que se están buscando duplicados consecutivos, separados por espacios, hay 2 puntos a corregir sobre el código que estás intentando:

1. En el patrón utilizado, sólo se está buscando 1 palabra consecutiva con `\s+\1\b+`, ya que el último `+` sólo repite a `\b` (y es innecesario). En cambio, de debería repetir a todo este subpatrón, agrupando con `(?:\s+\1)+\b`.
2. Se está utilizando primero un bucle para hallar las coincidencias, y luego reemplazar el string encontrado, algo que puede llevar a reemplazar en lugares equivocados. En cambio, se debería utilizar [Matcher.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) para realizar todos los reemplazos con un único llamado al método. Como reemplazo, usaremos `$1` para referirnos al texto capturado de la primer palabra.

Regex:

```
\b(\w+)(?: +\1)+\b
```

Reemplazo:

```
$1
```

Texto:

```
Hola hola hOla
```

Resultado:

```
Hola
```

Código:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(?: +\\1)+\\b";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

final String reemplazo = "$1";

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = in.nextLine();
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

//Se reemplazan todas las ocurrencias
input = m.replaceAll(reemplazo);

System.out.println(input);
```

Demo:

http://ideone.com/2oOOhI

---

Sin embargo, la solución anterior no considera tildes en las palabras. Para considerarlos, se puede utilizar el modificador [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).

```java
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```